# delay controller initialization after service is executed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

i have 2 controller in the same view. 
- Parent controller : ServiceController ( defined in application.js -> &routeProvider)
 - Child controller : LanguageController ( defined in the view -> ng-controller )

i want to pass a value retrieved by a rest asynchronous method ($resource.query()) in ServiceController to LanguageController

How can i do make the view waiting until the query finished ?

Thank you very much

ServiceController

```
ServiceController.controller('ServiceController', ['$scope' , '$routeParams', 'datas', 'GetService',
    function ServiceController($scope, $routeParams, datas , GetService) {


    $scope.serviceId = $routeParams.serviceId;
    $scope.serviceName = $routeParams.serviceName ;


    var paramsService = {
        serviceId : $scope.serviceId,
        serviceName : $scope.serviceName 
    };


    GetService.query(paramsService , function(serviceDetails) {
        $scope.serviceDetails = serviceDetails ;
        datas.setArrayData(serviceDetails); //service which allow to send datas to LanguageController

    });

}]);
```

LanguageController

```
LanguageController.controller('LanguageController', function ServiceByLanguageController(
        $scope, $http, $routeParams, datas) {


    $scope.listLanguage = datas.getDatas(); // empty because of the asynchronous method

});
```

Comment: since it's async as you point out, you need a way to inform your other controller that the data has been set, this is doable via $broadcast and $on

Comment: updated my answer, forgot that the two controllers are parent/child, so you don't really need to set data in the service as the child sees the parent scope data; adjusted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing data between controllers is easily done via $broadcast/$emit and $on

$broadcast - pass event/data down through child scopes
$emit - pass event/data up through parent scopes
$on - do something when event is caught

Your modified code, which should woak as you want

```
ServiceController.controller('ServiceController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', 'datas', 'GetService',
    function ServiceController($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, datas , GetService) {


    $scope.serviceId = $routeParams.serviceId;
    $scope.serviceName = $routeParams.serviceName ;


    var paramsService = {
        serviceId : $scope.serviceId,
        serviceName : $scope.serviceName 
    };


    GetService.query(paramsService , function(serviceDetails) {
        $scope.serviceDetails = serviceDetails ;
        datas.setArrayData(serviceDetails); //service which allow to send datas to LanguageController
        // broadcast from rootScope that the data has been set
        // explanation: $rootScope.$broadcast('eventNameYouWantToGive', dataYouWantToPassIfAny);
        $rootScope.$broadcast('dataSetInServiceContoller'); // just launch event saying data is set, no data passed
    });

}]);

LanguageController.controller('LanguageController', function ServiceByLanguageController($scope, $http, $routeParams, datas) {

    // $scope.$on('eventNameYouWantToCatch', function(event, dataYouWantToCatchIfAny){})
    $scope.$on('dataSetInServiceContoller', function(event, anyDataPassed){
        console.log('optionalDataPassed', anyDataPassed);
        $scope.listLanguage = datas.getDatas(); // this should no longer be empty
    });

});
```

This could also be done via HTML and JS, since one controller is a child of another, the Language controller will see all the data that the Service controller sees, so you don't really need to broadcast (which is useful for controllers on same page that are not hierarchical, but next to each other)

```
<div ng-controller="ServiceController"> 

    <div ng-if="serviceDetails" ng-controller="LanguageController"> <!-- Initialize when serviceDetails of $scope is defined -->
         <!-- -->

    </div>

</div>
```

This way when your `$scope.serviceDetails`  is defined in Service controller, the HTML will initialize the Language controller.

Comment: Thank you very much , i was trying to find a solution starting from 'resolve' in $routeProvider but your solution is much better and fluid.

Comment: 'resolve' is a good method if the controller has its own view path